# How should I indicate that the user correctly chose the incorrect option?

Tags: interaction-design

I have a language-learning app that shows the user a sentence with an extraneous word added that doesn't make sense in the context, and they have to choose which word doesn't belong:

[image: Choose the word that does not belong]

When they tap a word, it marks it with a red X, indicating this is the one that they chose as incorrect.

[image]

One user gave feedback that the red X was confusing since it looked like an indication that they answered the question incorrectly.

It seems inherently confusing, because there are two contradictory ideas of "correct" and "incorrect" at the same time, i.e. if the *word* is incorrect, the *user's selection* is correct, and vice versa if the word is correct, the user's selection is incorrect.

What is the best way to indicate to a user that they have correctly chosen the incorrect option?

Comment: I don't know Japanese, but is the word extra like "This sentence has *box* six words" or is it wrong, like "This sentence has *yellow* words"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes you got the right idea. The sentence in the screenshot is "When he had read 10 pages, I had already read *floor* 60 pages."

Comment: Not really enough for an answer: You could also place the X over the character/word. A thin X (so the character stays readable enough) and a red background

Comment: Or (@Martijn) a strikeout rather than a cross.  A slash would probably look better than an <s>html-style line</s>

Comment: Have you considered reframing as "the word that should be removed" rather than "the word that is incorrect"?  (Because its problem is contextual, not inherent.)

Comment: The phrasing "How should I indicate that the user correctly chose the incorrect option?" is flawed. Reset your thinking to "How should I indicate that the user is correct?"

Comment: Just use sth like "well done!" instead of "correct"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- If the word is in the wrong place, the logical situation when the user answers right, is the word leaving its position
- If the choice is correct, the color should not be red
- If the choice is wrong, the word stays in the same place and changes its color to red

[image: s]

---

[image]

---

Comment: A good companion to this might be rephrasing the question to "Tap the word that should be removed from the sentence", or something like that - positive rather than negative phrasing.

Comment: It would be really cool if it animated: bad word slides out, rest of words slide together to fill the gap, DING congratulations green success

Comment: Examples 2 and 3 would not work well if the correct answer is in the first line; ditto if there are 3 or more lines of text and the correct answer is in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Alternatively, just make the extraneous word fade out (whether or not the rest of the text animates to close the gap) -- turn it blue or green to indicate the correct word was selected, then fade it out. It provides a positive animation and allows the user to see the proper sentence. As an aside, don't lean too heavily on green/correct and red/incorrect -- red/green colorblindness renders these distinctions moot, and is reasonably common.

Answer (score 9):

Keep the focus on their choice as the rest is irrelevant at that very moment, mute everything else.

[image]

[image]

You can also slowly fade the other words back in if they are allowed another chance after they have failed.

If you want you can forgo the correct or incorrect message completely, but make sure you keep the colour blind in mind (example of correct answer, word is in green):

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about greying out the extraneous word, but this is even better!

Comment: I'm not sure I like this: as it makes the sentence hard to read and puts so much focus on what "should not be there". If the goal is to learn how to make sentences or similar you wish to show the "corrected" result in a prominent place.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of showing it with a red X, you could either

- move the word out of the sentence to somewhere else in the screen
- hide the word altogether

In both cases, you can optionally move the remainders of the sentence together. Both have the advantage that what you see in the end is a complete, correct sentence.

Other than that, questions asked 'in the negative' will always be harder to grasp and validate that those which have a 'positive' wording. I like [@DavidZ's suggestion in the comments](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/137084/how-should-i-indicate-that-the-user-correctly-chose-the-incorrect-option/137085#comment216637_137086) to change it into a positive statement like "Tap the word that should be removed from the sentence".

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that @Danielillo's answer gives you trouble when the 'not belonging word' is on the first line.

What about this?

When the user selected:
[image]

When the answer is correct:
[image]

When the answer is incorrect:
[image]

Comment: Please avoid leaning on red/green to indicate incorrect/correct. It is not user-friendly for colorblind users, which is somewhere between 4-10% of the male population (depending on ethnicity; it's more prevalent in some population groups than others). Otherwise I think this is a pretty solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense, I would think about the operation the user has performed and how you communicate the result of that operation.

Either the user has succeeded or failed in the task. I would separate that from the concept of the word being "wrong".

How I would solve this is to indicate to the user what they have selected in an obvious way, but one which doesn't have a semantic meaning, then focus on communicating the success of failure of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the selection and activate the  [CHECK]  button.

---

[image: select]
[image: check]

---

If the selection is wrong, display "Incorrect", and depending on the design of the program flow, either provide a  [NEXT]  or  [TRY AGAIN]  option.

---

[image: incorrect next]
[image: incorrect try again]

---

If  [TRY AGAIN]  is an option, when clicked, remove the "Incorrect" message, slightly dim the highlight of the previously selected wrong character, and display the dimmed  [CHECK]  button.

When the user makes another selection activate the  [CHECK]  button.

---

[image: check again dimmed]
[image: check again]

---

Upon a correct selection, dim the correctly selected character, display "Correct", and activate the  [NEXT]  button.

---

[image: correct]

---